# How callbacks work and global data synchronization

Tags: c, unix, callback, synchronization, global-variables

I am having some difficulty understanding callbacks and program flow, synchronization issues.

Lets say I have a global variable g_peers. And I register a callback with a system app which will notify me with peer events like - joins/leave/change. Now in the callback, I am modifying g_peers based on the event and associated information. In other parts of the code (i.e the regular code flow) I have functions which read from g_peers.

Now will this result in synchronization issues? Lets say I am in the middle of reading from g_peers when a peer leaves and callback is invoked which modifies g_peers.

How does callback work? Is the normal flow interrupted till the callback finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables in a multithreaded enviornment always need to be synchronized for concurrent access through multiple threads.
If your environment is multithreaded then the callback will be called in a separate thread and hence must be synchronized.
If your environment is single threaded then no synchronization is needed.

**What is a Callback?**

In simple terms, a **Callback function** is one that is not called explicitly by the programmer. Instead, there is some mechanism that continually waits for events to occur, and it will call selected functions in response to particular events.
    This mechanism is typically used when a operation(function) can take long time for execution and the caller of the function does not want to wait till the operation is complete, but does wish to be intimated of the outcome of the operation. Typically, Callback functions help implement such an ***asynchronous mechanism***, wherein the caller registers to get inimated about the result of the time consuming processing and continuous other operations while at a later point of time, the caller gets informed of the result.

Comment: My program is single threaded. Does having a callback make it multithreaded?

Comment: @HappyGoLucky: No it doesn't. A good example of singlethreaded Framework is Brew Framework which does employ callbacks.

Comment: Lets take the example I gave in my question. In the main program loop, say there's a function called DisplayPeers() which is currently being executed. In a for loop each peer info is printed on screen. During this, the callback is invoked and the callback memsets the g_peers to 0. After callback is done, control goes back to DisplayPeers. It continues where it left. But now the g_peers is empty. Will this not cause a problem?

Comment: @HappyGoLucky: The behavior specifically depends on the framework that you are using and how it supports callback in the single threaded environment.The callback may not be asynchronous at all in some frameworks.You will need to check the documentation of whichever fwk you are using.

Comment: I am not using any framework as such. Just a simple c program on unix.

Comment: @HappyGoLucky: Why do you say your program is not multithreaded? The entity you register to for callback might call your program in its own thread.

Comment: That is exactly my question to begin with. I am not explicitly using any threads. I am just registering a callback with a system library. When certain network events happen, this callback will be invoked. Now : Is this callback code executed in a different thread? Is the regular processing flow interrupted while the callback is executed? Is it safe to modify global variable from inside the callback? I am just not clear about these.

Comment: @HappyGoLucky:The OP didn't actually reflect your real Question then.Callback will be called in a separate thread,this thread will be an thread spawned by the system library.Given that Yes You need to protect your global with synchronization.Also, You should not do a lot of processing in Callback threads,reason is You will be hogging the thread of another entity and some entity's do not really like it,If you intend to do lot of processing,Ideally You should switch the context and do the processing in one of the threads spwaned by your Application/Middleware.Hope this clears things better now.